# How to close a file using Shell?

Tags: windows, shell

I have a file opened named "C/Users/Desktop/textfile.txt". How do I close this using a shell script? I have tried taskkill, shutdown, "exec 1>&-" and others. Since I am new to shell, I am unable to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

textfile.txt is a non-executable file.  That means you can't 'run' it, or 'kill' it.  However, you can delete it - that is if some other process is not holding a lock on it.

If you want to release the lock, you have to first find the process that is holding a handle to this file, kill that process, and then the OS will let you delete the file.

From shell (command line), you can use this tool handle (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to identify which process is holding your handle.  Once you get the pid (process id) from that tool, you can use taskkill to terminate that process and release the lock on that file.

`c:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite>handle.exe | findstr /i "c:/users/desktop/textfile.txt"`

All said, you want to be careful when you terminate processes abruptly like this.  The process won't get a chance to clean up behind itself.